# antisymmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Take $\Omega$ an antisymmetric matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $D$ a symmetric matrix,
Then $\Omega D + D\Omega$ is antisymmetric and since we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ there exists vector $\theta$ such that $(\Omega D + D\Omega)v = \theta \times v$, where $\times$ denote the cross product.

If I call $\omega$ the vector that caracterize $\Omega$ in term of cross product, I would like to show that $\theta = D(\omega)$ or an equality like this up to a constant ($\theta = CD(\omega)$)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use this equality:
$$u \times (Av) - (Au) \times v = A(u\times v)$$

Comment: If I have this equality the result is obvious, actually my point is to understand where this equality comes from.

Comment: That's just some ugly computations. Cf. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) for something similar with a proof.